# Prove that $G=\mathbb{Z}_{n_1} \times ... \times \mathbb{Z}_{n_k}$ is cyclic $\iff n_1,...,n_k$ are pairwise coprime

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, least-common-multiple, direct-product

Prove that $G=\mathbb{Z}_{n_1} \times ... \times \mathbb{Z}_{n_k}$ is cyclic $\iff n_1,...,n_k$ are pairwise coprime.

In order to prove this fact, I was asked to prove:

1. $lg=e_G$ (the identity element of G), $\forall g\in G$ where $l=LCM(n_1,...,n_k)$
2. $\exists g\in G$ such that $o(g)=l$, where $o(g)$ denotes the order of $g$.

I have done both of these smaller proofs and am curious about how they fit into the larger picture. Hints are appreciated, thank you!

Comment: By o(g) do you mean the order of g? And is 0 meant to be the identity in G?

Comment: Yes and yes. I will edit that in, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using those is easy, notice that the least common multiple of $n_1,n_2, \dots n_k$ is equal to the product if and only if they are pairwise coprime.

So if $n_1,n_2\dots n_k$ are not pairwise coprime we have that $l<|G|$, and we have by the first result that the order of every element in $G$ is smaller than $|G|$, so the group cannot be cyclic.

On the other hand if $n_1,n_2,\dots n_k$ are pairwise coprime then $l=|G|$, so by result two we have that there is an element $g\in G$ with $o(g)=|G|$, and so the group is cyclic.

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer! How is that you know $n_1,...,n_k=n_1n_2...n_k \iff n_1,...,n_k$ are pairwise coprime?

Comment: you might want to ask it as a separate question, there are various ways to do this.